# How to configure Bash to use lsd for tab-completion?

Tags: command-line, bash, ls

*For the sake of the question, assume I'm on the most-recent (stable) LTS release of Ubuntu.*

I've installed a replacement for the `ls` command. In this case, that replacement is [lsd](https://github.com/lsd-rs/lsd). The same question applies to other replacements for `ls`, but that's what I choose to use.

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get install wget
# wget 'https://github.com/lsd-rs/lsd/releases/download/v1.0.0/lsd_1.0.0_amd64.deb'
# apt-get install ./lsd_1.0.0_amd64.deb
```

I also have a folder named `demo`, with some files in it (`a.py` and `b.txt`). I can run standard `ls`, of course:

```
# ls demo
a.py  b.txt
```

Doing `lsd demo` also works:

```
# lsd demo
 a.py   b.txt
```

[image]

However, when I do this, it simply lists the filenames.

```
# cat demo/[TAB][TAB]
a.py   b.txt
```

Instead of just listing the filenames as if I ran `ls`, how can I configure "tab file list completion" in Bash to show the output of `lsd` (so I get the icons) instead of stock `ls`? If it's easier, feel free to generalize this question to "how can I run an arbitrary command instead of `ls` for Bash completion"

Comment: Parsing the output of `ls` is hazardous. It can't be done safely for arbitrary filenames unless you have something like the `--zero` option of GNU ls. Does `lsd` have something like that? Side note: you have `lsd a.txt` instead of `lsd demo` in the example.

Comment: @muru Fixed that, thanks! It doesn't look like it has `--zero` as an option. Why would you need to parse its output, though...? Does Bash actually parse the output, or could it just call `lsd` and have it print the output (with the desired glob)?

Comment: Just printing the `lsd` output won't be sufficient, right? For menu-complete at least  (where you can press tab repeatedly to cycle through completions), and possibly other completion methods, bash will need to know what the items are, and for that it needs to be able to parse the entries accurately. The built-in readline library usually handles filename completion, so it doesn't need to parse any output.